# How do I change the text of a button when clicked, in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I want to change the text when `this.isDisabled` is set to false or vice versa, when the button is clicked.
I have also used `this.btn.value`, but it threw me an error.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div style="display:flex;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;justify-self:center">
    <h2>Welcome to {{name}} </h2>

    <input [disabled]="isDisabled" [id]="myId" type="text" value="Vishwas"> 

    <button id="changeText" (click)="enableDisable()">Edit</button>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})


export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Something';
  public myId = "testId";
  public isDisabled = true;
  public btn = document.getElementById('changeText');
  

  enableDisable(){
    if(this.isDisabled){
      this.isDisabled=false;
      this.btn.textContent="Save";
    }
    else{
      this.isDisabled=true;
      this.btn.textContent="Edit";
    }
    console.log(this.isDisabled);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're going to want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background). Don't manipulate the DOM with Angular. It's completely anti-pattern.

Comment: on which version of angular you are working on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**codeSolution**:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-or2wqk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
<button id="changeText" (click)="enableDisable()">
  <span *ngIf="isDisabled; else prompt">
    changeText
  </span>
</button>
<ng-template #prompt>
  Save
</ng-template>

  import { Component} from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      isDisabled: boolean = false;
    
      enableDisable() {
        this.isDisabled = this.isDisabled ? false : true;
      }
    }
```

check if this works for you

**Explanation**

- on click of button enableDisable() function is called where we toggle
  isDisabled flag
- content of the button is changed conditionally on isDisabled flag
- if isDisabled  is true "changeText" else "Save" will display (used Angular Ngif directive for this you can refer https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-else-then)

Comment: Yes, it works so fine. Thank you so much. Please let me know how did you do it, if you someday have a time?
Once again, thank you Brother..

Comment: welcome . ill edit this solution with an explanation today

Comment: @Anonymous added explanation

Answer (score 1):

I know the accepted answer works, but it's very overcomplicated. This is much simpler.

```html
<button (click)="isDisabled = !isDisabled">
    {{ isDisabled ? 'Edit' : 'Save' }}
</button>
```

```js
export class AppComponent {
    isDisabled: boolean = false;
}
```

Comment: Nice, looks simpler and works smooth. Thanks alot